# How do you win the zombies mode in Call of Duty Black ops

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops

The zombies game in Black ops (FPS one, not the top one) seems to have one obvious goal at the beginning: Restore the power. I've looked around the net and not seen any explanation of whether this is all you need to win or whether it then gets worse from there or what... Can anybody explain the progression of the game? are there limited rooms? Is there a win condition? Or do you just see how far you can go before being taken down?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The goal is to see how long you can last. Turning the power on just gives you access to fun toys around the map like traps and guns and whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Zombie mode is *a strange game. The only winning move is not to play*

Ultimately, you will lose to the horde. The point is simply to see how long you will last. TUrning on the power activates the power up

Answer (score 1):

Winning is not always achieved at finishing something; winning usually in the form of enjoyment. For this game, to be able to achieve that, you must play cooperatively. Don't do something stupid that would make you overrun by the zombies or piss-off your team-mates just like what those think they were already "Pros" on this game.

Always try to communicate with others and observe from those who already know this game.
Try to come-up with a good strategy and don't get in the way of other players. ^_^